# Efficient unsigned-to-signed cast avoiding implementation-defined behavior

Tags: c++, casting, integer, language-lawyer, integer-overflow

I want to define a function that takes an `unsigned int` as argument and returns an `int` congruent modulo UINT_MAX+1 to the argument.

A first attempt might look like this:

```
int unsigned_to_signed(unsigned n)
{
    return static_cast<int>(n);
}
```

But as any language lawyer knows, casting from unsigned to signed for values larger than INT_MAX is implementation-defined.

I want to implement this such that (a) it only relies on behavior mandated by the spec; and (b) it compiles into a no-op on any modern machine and optimizing compiler.

As for bizarre machines...  If there is no signed int congruent modulo UINT_MAX+1 to the unsigned int, let's say I want to throw an exception.  If there is more than one (I am not sure this is possible), let's say I want the largest one.

OK, second attempt:

```
int unsigned_to_signed(unsigned n)
{
    int int_n = static_cast<int>(n);

    if (n == static_cast<unsigned>(int_n))
        return int_n;

    // else do something long and complicated
}
```

I do not much care about the efficiency when I am not on a typical twos-complement system, since in my humble opinion that is unlikely.  And if my code becomes a bottleneck on the omnipresent sign-magnitude systems of 2050, well, I bet someone can figure that out and optimize it then.

Now, this second attempt is pretty close to what I want.  Although the cast to `int` is implementation-defined for some inputs, the cast back to `unsigned` is guaranteed by the standard to preserve the value modulo UINT_MAX+1.  So the conditional does check exactly what I want, and it will compile into nothing on any system I am likely to encounter.

However...  I am still casting to `int` without first checking whether it will invoke implementation-defined behavior.  On some hypothetical system in 2050 it could do who-knows-what.  So let's say I want to avoid that.

Question:  What should my "third attempt" look like?

To recap, I want to:

- Cast from unsigned int to signed int
- Preserve the value mod UINT_MAX+1
- Invoke only standard-mandated behavior
- Compile into a no-op on a typical twos-complement machine with optimizing compiler

[Update]

Let me give an example to show why this is not a trivial question.

Consider a hypothetical C++ implementation with the following properties:

- `sizeof(int)` equals 4
- `sizeof(unsigned)` equals 4
- `INT_MAX` equals 32767
- `INT_MIN` equals -2<sup>32</sup> + 32768
- `UINT_MAX` equals 2<sup>32</sup> - 1
- Arithmetic on `int` is modulo 2<sup>32</sup> (into the range `INT_MIN` through `INT_MAX`)
- `std::numeric_limits<int>::is_modulo` is true
- Casting unsigned `n` to int preserves the value for 0 <= n <= 32767 and yields *zero* otherwise

On this hypothetical implementation, there is exactly one `int` value congruent (mod UINT_MAX+1) to each `unsigned` value.  So my question would be well-defined.

I claim that this hypothetical C++ implementation fully conforms to the C++98, C++03, and C++11 specifications.  I admit I have not memorized every word of all of them...  But I believe I have read the relevant sections carefully.  So if you want me to accept your answer, you either must (a) cite a spec that rules out this hypothetical implementation or (b) handle it correctly.

Indeed, a correct answer must handle *every* hypothetical implementation permitted by the standard. That is what "invoke only standard-mandated behavior" means, by definition.

Incidentally, note that `std::numeric_limits<int>::is_modulo` is utterly useless here for multiple reasons.  For one thing, it can be `true` even if unsigned-to-signed casts do not work for large unsigned values.  For another, it can be `true` even on one's-complement or sign-magnitude systems, if arithmetic is simply modulo the entire integer range.  And so on.  If your answer depends on `is_modulo`, it's wrong.

[Update 2]

[hvd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208789/768469) taught me something:  My hypothetical C++ implementation for integers is *not* permitted by modern C.  The C99 and C11 standards are very specific about the representation of signed integers; indeed, they only permit twos-complement, ones-complement, and sign-magnitude (section 6.2.6.2 paragraph (2); ).

But C++ is not C.  As it turns out, this fact lies at the very heart of my question.

The original C++98 standard was based on the much older C89, which says (section 3.1.2.5):

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but
>   different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword
>   unsigned)  that uses the same amount of storage (including sign
>   information) and has the same alignment requirements.  The range of
>   nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the
>   corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of the
>   same value in each type is the same.

C89 says nothing about only having one sign bit or only allowing twos-complement/ones-complement/sign-magnitude.

The C++98 standard adopted this language nearly verbatim (section 3.9.1 paragraph (3)):

> For each of the signed integer types, there exists a corresponding
>   (but different) *unsigned integer type*: "`unsigned char`", "`unsigned
>   short int`", "`unsigned int`", and "`unsigned long int`", each of
>   which occupies the same amount of storage and has the same alignment
>   requirements (3.9) as the corresponding signed integer type ; that
>   is, each *signed integer* type has the same object representation as
>   its corresponding *unsigned integer* type. The range of nonnegative
>   values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding
>   unsigned integer type, and the value representation of each
>   corresponding signed/unsigned type shall be the same.

The C++03 standard uses essentially identical language, as does C++11.

No standard C++ spec constrains its signed integer representations to any C spec, as far as I can tell.  And there is nothing mandating a single sign bit or anything of the kind.  All it says is that *non-negative* signed integers must be a subrange of the corresponding unsigned.

So, again I claim that INT_MAX=32767 with INT_MIN=-2<sup>32</sup>+32768 is permitted.  If your answer assumes otherwise, it is incorrect unless you cite a **C++** standard proving me wrong.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Actually, I stated exactly what I want in that case:  "If there is no signed int congruent modulo UINT_MAX+1 to the unsigned int, let's say I want to throw an exception."  That is, I want the "right" signed int provided it exists.  If it does not exist -- as might happen in the case of e.g. padding bits or ones-complement representations -- I want to detect that and handle it for that particular invocation of the cast.

Comment: sorry, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Btw, I think that in your hypothetical tricky implementation `int` needs at least 33 bits to represent it. I know it's only a footnote, so you can argue it's non-normative, but I think footnote 49 in C++11 is intended to be *true* (since it's a definition of a term used in the standard) and it doesn't contradict anything explicitly stated in normative text. So all negative values must be represented by a bit pattern in which the highest bit is set, and hence you can't cram `2^32 - 32768` of them into 32 bits. Not that your argument relies in any way on the size of `int`.

Comment: And regarding your edits in hvd's answer, I think you've mis-interpreted note 49. You say that sign-magnitude is forbidden, but it isn't. You've read it as: "the values represented by successive bits are additive, begin with 1, and (are multiplied by successive integral power of 2, except perhaps for the bit with the highest position)". I believe it should be read, "the values represented by successive bits (are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral power of 2), except perhaps for the bit with the highest position". That is, all bets are off if the high bit is set.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Your interpretation may be correct.  If so, it does rule out my hypothetical...  But it also introduces a truly vast number of possibilities, making this question extremely hard to answer. This actually looks like a bug in the spec to me.  (Apparently, the C committee thought so and fixed it throroughly in C99.  I wonder why C++11 did not adopt their approach?)

Comment: If an implementation uses ones'-complement or sign-magnitude format, are boolean operators defined as operating on the raw bits, or are they defined as operating in a fashion consistent with two's-complement format (in which case the only significance of the representation would be (1) the behavior of ~INT_MAX, and (2) unions or other techniques of aliasing types.

Comment: @supercat: I think you mean "bitwise operators", not "Boolean operators". (The latter operate on Booleans; e.g. `&&` or `||`.) I believe the answer to your question is that the bitwise operators (like `&` and `|`) operate on the "value representation" of the integer. If you want to ensure behavior "consistent with two's-complement format" you need to cast the arguments to their unsigned forms.

Comment: @Nemo: In other words, given `int n;`, truly portable computation of "n mod 16" [as opposed to "n remainder 16"] requires `(unsigned)n & 15` rather than simply `n & 15`?  I wonder how much code deliberately uses bitwise operators on anything other than two's-complement values?  I wish the C standards committee would add standard ways of specifying that a program should either use particular integer semantics or refuse compilation; as it is, the language makes it much easier to write code which looks correct but will break on some reasonable implementations than to write code which is portable.

Comment: What about casting moving to pointers:

`int32_t magic = -45;`

`uint32_t& magicu = *((int32_t*) (&magic));`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Expanding on user71404's answer:

```
int f(unsigned x)
{
    if (x <= INT_MAX)
        return static_cast<int>(x);

    if (x >= INT_MIN)
        return static_cast<int>(x - INT_MIN) + INT_MIN;

    throw x; // Or whatever else you like
}
```

If `x >= INT_MIN` (keep the promotion rules in mind, `INT_MIN` gets converted to `unsigned`), then `x - INT_MIN <= INT_MAX`, so this won't have any overflow.

If that is not obvious, take a look at the claim "If `x >= -4u`, then `x + 4 <= 3`.", and keep in mind that `INT_MAX` will be equal to at least the mathematical value of -INT_MIN - 1.

On the most common systems, where `!(x <= INT_MAX)` implies `x >= INT_MIN`, the optimizer should be able (and on my system, is able) to remove the second check, determine that the two `return` statements can be compiled to the same code, and remove the first check too. Generated assembly listing:

```
__Z1fj:
LFB6:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

The hypothetical implementation in your question:

- INT_MAX equals 32767
- INT_MIN equals -2<sup>32</sup> + 32768

is not possible, so does not need special consideration. `INT_MIN` will be equal to either `-INT_MAX`, or to `-INT_MAX - 1`. This follows from C's representation of integer types (6.2.6.2), which requires `n` bits to be value bits, one bit to be a sign bit, and only allows one single trap representation (not including representations that are invalid because of padding bits), namely the one that would otherwise represent negative zero / `-INT_MAX - 1`. C++ doesn't allow any integer representations beyond what C allows.

***Update***: Microsoft's compiler apparently does not notice that `x > 10` and `x >= 11` test the same thing. It only generates the desired code if `x >= INT_MIN` is replaced with `x > INT_MIN - 1u`, which it can detect as the negation of `x <= INT_MAX` (on this platform).

[Update from questioner (Nemo), elaborating on our discussion below]

I now believe this answer works in all cases, but for complicated reasons.  I am likely to award the bounty to this solution, but I want to capture all the gory details in case anybody cares.

Let's start with C++11, section 18.3.3:

> Table 31 describes the header `<climits>`.
>
> ...
>
> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header `<limits.h>`.

Here, "Standard C" means C99, whose specification severely constrains the representation of signed integers.  They are just like unsigned integers, but with one bit dedicated to "sign" and zero or more bits dedicated to "padding".  The padding bits do not contribute to the value of the integer, and the sign bit contributes only as twos-complement, ones-complement, or sign-magnitude.

Since C++11 inherits the `<climits>` macros from C99, INT_MIN is either -INT_MAX or -INT_MAX-1, and hvd's code is guaranteed to work.  (Note that, due to the padding, INT_MAX could be much less than UINT_MAX/2...  But thanks to the way signed->unsigned casts work, this answer handles that fine.)

C++03/C++98 is trickier.  It uses the same wording to inherit `<climits>` from "Standard C", but now "Standard C" means C89/C90.

All of these -- C++98, C++03, C89/C90 -- have the wording I give in my question, but also include this (C++03 section 3.9.1 paragraph 7):

> The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a
>   pure binary numeration system.(44) [*Example*: this International
>   Standard permits 2’s complement, 1’s complement and signed magnitude
>   representations for integral types.]

Footnote (44) defines "pure binary numeration system":

> A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0
>   and 1, in which the values represented by successive bits are
>   additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral
>   power of 2, except perhaps for the bit with the highest position.

What is interesting about this wording is that it contradicts itself, because the definition of "pure binary numeration system" does not permit a sign/magnitude representation!  It does allow the high bit to have, say, the value -2<sup>n-1</sup> (twos complement) or -(2<sup>n-1</sup>-1) (ones complement).  But there is no value for the high bit that results in sign/magnitude.

Anyway, my "hypothetical implementation" does not qualify as "pure binary" under this definition, so it is ruled out.

However, the fact that the high bit is special means we can imagine it contributing any value at all: A small positive value, huge positive value, small negative value, or huge negative value.  (If the sign bit can contribute -(2<sup>n-1</sup>-1), why not -(2<sup>n-1</sup>-2)?  etc.)

So, let's imagine a signed integer representation that assigns a wacky value to the "sign" bit.

A small positive value for the sign bit would result in a positive range for `int` (possibly as large as `unsigned`), and hvd's code handles that just fine.

A huge positive value for the sign bit would result in `int` having a maximum larger than `unsigned`, which is is forbidden.

A huge negative value for the sign bit would result in `int` representing a non-contiguous range of values, and other wording in the spec rules that out.

Finally, how about a sign bit that contributes a small negative quantity?  Could we have a 1 in the "sign bit" contribute, say, -37 to the value of the int?  So then INT_MAX would be (say) 2<sup>31</sup>-1 and INT_MIN would be -37?

This would result in some numbers having two representations...  But ones-complement gives two representations to zero, and that is allowed according to the "Example".  Nowhere does the spec say that zero is the *only* integer that might have two representations.  So I think this new hypothetical is allowed by the spec.

Indeed, any negative value from -1 down to `-INT_MAX-1` appears to be permissible as a value for the "sign bit", but nothing smaller (lest the range be non-contiguous).  In other words, `INT_MIN` might be anything from `-INT_MAX-1` to -1.

Now, guess what?  For the second cast in hvd's code to avoid implementation-defined behavior, we just need `x - (unsigned)INT_MIN` less than or equal to `INT_MAX`.  We just showed `INT_MIN` is at least `-INT_MAX-1`.  Obviously, `x` is at most `UINT_MAX`.  Casting a negative number to unsigned is the same as adding `UINT_MAX+1`.  Put it all together:

```
x - (unsigned)INT_MIN <= INT_MAX
```

if and only if

```
UINT_MAX - (INT_MIN + UINT_MAX + 1) <= INT_MAX
-INT_MIN-1 <= INT_MAX
-INT_MIN <= INT_MAX+1
INT_MIN >= -INT_MAX-1
```

That last is what we just showed, so even in this perverse case, the code actually works.

That exhausts all of the possibilities, thus ending this extremely academic exercise.

Bottom line:  There is some seriously under-specified behavior for signed integers in C89/C90 that got inherited by C++98/C++03.  It is fixed in C99, and C++11 indirectly inherits the fix by incorporating `<limits.h>` from C99.  But even C++11 retains the self-contradictory "pure binary representation" wording...

Comment: Question updated.  I am down-voting this answer (for now) to discourage others...  I will un-down-vote later because answer is interesting.  (Correct for C, but wrong for C++.  I think.)

Comment: @Nemo The C standard applies to C++ in this case; at the very least, the values in `<limits.h>` are defined in the C++ standard as having the same meaning as in the C standard, so all of C's requirements for `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are inherited in C++. You're correct that C++03 refers to C90, and C90 is vague about the allowed integer representations, but the C99 change (inherited at least via `<limits.h>` by C++11, hopefully also in a more straightforward way) to limit it to those three was one that codified existing practise: no other implementations existed.

Comment: I agree that the meaning of `INT_MIN` etc. are inherited from C.  But that does not mean the _values_ are.  (Indeed, how could they, since every implementation is different?)  Your inference that `INT_MIN` is within 1 of `-INT_MAX` depends on wording that simply does not appear in any C++ spec.  So while C++ does inherit the semantic meaning of the macros, the spec does not provide (or inherit) the wording that supports your inference.  This appears to be an oversight in the C++ spec that prevents a fully-conforming efficient unsigned-to-signed cast.

Comment: @Nemo If you (perhaps correctly) claim that C++ allows other representations, then on such an implementation, I claim that `INT_MIN` *isn't* required to be the minimal representable value of type `int`, because as far as C is concerned, if the type does not match the requirements of `int`, the C standard cannot possibly cover that implementation in any way whatsoever, and the C++ standard does not provide any definition of it other than "what the C standard says". I'll check if there's a more straightforward explanation.

Comment: @Nemo There's also C++11 [basic.fundamental]p7: "The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system. [Example: this International Standard permits 2's complement, 1's complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types. --end example ]" This would still disallow your hypothetical implementation, but it would perhaps allow others that aren't allowed in C.

Comment: I would say my hypothetical representation _is_ "a pure binary numeration system".  It's just biased a little funny :-).  Still, since the C++ spec does say `<climits>` has the same contents as "the Standard C header `<limits.h>`", it does follow that `INT_MIN` etc. must be valid for C.  So that takes care of C++11 (but not C++03, for which "Standard C" meant C90).  I will likely wind up accepting this answer.

Comment: Hm, reading the C99 spec again, I do not see any wording mandating at most one "trap representation".  (In fact it explicitly allows one or more bits as "padding" in the signed representation.)  So bias my example the other way (INT_MIN=-32768, INT_MAX=2^32-32769) and I think it might conform even to the C specification...

Comment: @Nemo There's a footnote attached to "pure binary numeration system": "A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values represented by successive bits are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral power of 2, except perhaps for the bit with the highest position." In other words, at least all but one are value bits, and a remaining bit may have a special meaning (such as the sign bit); I believe that disallows your implementation, because it does not derive the value from the value bits when the special bit is 0.

Comment: @Nemo Yes, C allows integer types to have padding bits, but they play no role here. A signed integer type with 31 value bits, 1 sign bit, and 232 padding bits must have either exactly 2**32 or exactly 2**32-1 valid values. Which bits are padding bits does not depend on the value.

Comment: @Nemo But you're right, I was sloppy with my wording there. Note included in my answer.

Comment: 6.2.6.2 (2) makes it clear that some of the value bits in the unsigned representation can be padding bits in the signed representation:  "If there are M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M ≤ N".  (So N-M counts padding bits plus sign bit.)  You may have me on "pure binary" in C++11 :-).  But I do not think -`INT_MAX` is necessarily within 1 of `INT_MIN` by the C spec.

Comment: @Nemo Yes, C allows, for example, `int` to have 31 value bits, 1 sign bit, and 32 padding bits, while `unsigned` has 64 value bits. I believe it also allows `int` to have 31 value bits, 1 sign bit, no padding bits, while `unsigned` has 31 value bits and one padding bit. I took such implementations into account when coming up with my answer. For such implementations, `INT_MIN` will still be either `-INT_MAX` or `-INT_MAX - 1`; `INT_MAX` just won't be equal to `UINT_MAX / 2`.

Comment: Ok I see.  So C99 is OK, C++11 is OK, and C90 and C++03 are under specified.  Unless someone finds a viable solution for all of them, you will get the 500 bounty.  Thanks for the discussion

Comment: @Nemo Glad it helps, and I'm very curious to see if someone else comes up with a correct C90/C++03 solution. The only thing I can come up with is what I have in this answer, combined with a check that the return value converted back to `unsigned` is equal to the parameter, and if not, brute force it, checking each possible value from `INT_MIN` all the way to `INT_MAX`. But that's obviously a very poor solution. :)

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer to add some elaboration (references etc.), including some of the citations we have covered here?  I want the Q&A to be correct in case anybody stumbles across this in the future.  Or would you prefer that I just edit my question?

Comment: @hvd: The OP (or his source!) constructed an example thwarting your answer. I believe that it was added after my answer (not sure, but I think that I would have noticed that!). Anyway, consider your expression `static_cast<int>(x - INT_MIN)`. It's only evaluated if x >= INT_MIN, after promotion of INT_MIN to unsigned. With the OP's INT_MIN = -2^n + 32768, promotion yields 32768, so let's set x at a round 1 million + 32768. Subtracting INT_MIN which is congruent to 32768, then yields a round 1 million. Which is outside the OP's example `int` range, so the cast invokes impl. def. behavior... :(

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That was one of the points addressed in these comments, which Nemo has included in my answer: C++ doesn't allow that implementation, so no special consideration is needed.

Comment: This is gorgeous. No idea how I missed this question at the time.

Answer (score 20):

This code relies only on behavior, mandated by the spec, so requirement (a) is easily satisfied:

```
int unsigned_to_signed(unsigned n)
{
  int result = INT_MAX;

  if (n > INT_MAX && n < INT_MIN)
    throw runtime_error("no signed int for this number");

  for (unsigned i = INT_MAX; i != n; --i)
    --result;

  return result;
}
```

It's not so easy with requirement (b). This compiles into a no-op with gcc 4.6.3 (-Os, -O2, -O3) and with clang 3.0 (-Os, -O, -O2, -O3). Intel 12.1.0 refuses to optimize this. And I have no info about Visual C.

Comment: OK, this is awesome.  I wish I could split the bounty 80:20...  I suspect the compiler's reasoning goes:  If the loop does not terminate, `result` overflows; integer overflow is undefined; therefore the loop terminates; therefore `i == n` at termination; therefore `result` equals `n`.  I still have to prefer hvd's answer (for the non-pathological behavior on less-smart compilers), but this deserves more up-votes.

Comment: Unsigned are defined to be modulo.  The loop is also guaranteed to terminate because `n` is some unsigned value and `i` eventually must reach every unsigned value.

Answer (score 19):

The original answer solved the problem only for `unsigned` => `int`. What if we want to solve the general problem of "some unsigned type" to its corresponding signed type? Furthermore, the original answer was excellent at citing sections of the standard and analyzing some corner cases, but it did not really help me get a feel for why it worked, so this answer will try to give a strong conceptual basis. This answer will try to help explain "why", and use modern C++ features to try to simplify the code.

### C++20 answer

The problem has simplified dramatically with [P0907: Signed Integers are Two’s Complement](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html) and the [final wording P1236](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1236r1.html) that was voted into the C++20 standard. Now, the answer is as simple as possible:

```
template<std::unsigned_integral T>
constexpr auto cast_to_signed_integer(T const value) {
    return static_cast<std::make_signed_t<T>>(value);
}
```

That's it. A `static_cast` (or C-style cast) is finally guaranteed to do the thing you need for this question, and the thing many programmers thought it always did.

### C++17 answer

In C++17, things are much more complicated. We have to deal with three possible integer representations (two's complement, ones' complement, and sign-magnitude). Even in the case where we know it must be two's complement because we checked the range of possible values, the conversion of a value outside the range of the signed integer to that signed integer still gives us an implementation-defined result. We have to use tricks like we have seen in other answers.

First, here is the code for how to solve the problem generically:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<T>>>
constexpr auto cast_to_signed_integer(T const value) {
    using result = std::make_signed_t<T>;
    using result_limits = std::numeric_limits<result>;
    if constexpr (result_limits::min() + 1 != -result_limits::max()) {
        if (value == static_cast<T>(result_limits::max()) + 1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot convert the maximum possible unsigned to a signed value on this system");
        }
    }
    if (value <= result_limits::max()) {
        return static_cast<result>(value);
    } else {
        using promoted_unsigned = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) <= sizeof(unsigned), unsigned, T>;
        using promoted_signed = std::make_signed_t<promoted_unsigned>;
        constexpr auto shift_by_window = [](auto x) {
            // static_cast to avoid conversion warning
            return x - static_cast<decltype(x)>(result_limits::max()) - 1;
        };
        return static_cast<result>(
            shift_by_window( // shift values from common range to negative range
                static_cast<promoted_signed>(
                    shift_by_window( // shift large values into common range
                        static_cast<promoted_unsigned>(value) // cast to avoid promotion to int
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This has a few more casts than the accepted answer, and that is to ensure there are no signed / unsigned mismatch warnings from your compiler and to properly handle integer promotion rules.

We first have a special case for systems that are not two's complement (and thus we must handle the maximum possible value specially because it doesn't have anything to map to). After that, we get to the real algorithm.

The second top-level condition is straightforward: we know the value is less than or equal to the maximum value, so it fits in the result type. The third condition is a little more complicated even with the comments, so some examples would probably help understand why each statement is necessary.

### Conceptual basis: the number line

First, what is this `window` concept? Consider the following number line:

```
   |   signed   |
<.........................>
          |  unsigned  |
```

It turns out that for two's complement integers, you can divide the subset of the number line that can be reached by either type into three equally sized categories:

```
- => signed only
= => both
+ => unsigned only

<..-------=======+++++++..>
```

This can be easily proven by considering the representation. An unsigned integer starts at `0` and uses all of the bits to increase the value in powers of 2. A signed integer is exactly the same for all of the bits except the sign bit, which is worth `-(2^position)` instead of `2^position`. This means that for all `n - 1` bits, they represent the same values. Then, unsigned integers have one more normal bit, which doubles the total number of values (in other words, there are just as many values with that bit set as without it set). The same logic holds for signed integers, except that all the values with that bit set are negative.

The other two legal integer representations, ones' complement and sign-magnitude, have all of the same values as two's complement integers except for one: the most negative value. C++ defines everything about integer types, except for `reinterpret_cast` (and the C++20 `std::bit_cast`), in terms of the range of representable values, not in terms of the bit representation. This means that our analysis will hold for each of these three representations as long as we do not ever try to create the trap representation. The unsigned value that would map to this missing value is a rather unfortunate one: the one right in the middle of the unsigned values. Fortunately, our first condition checks (at compile time) whether such a representation exists, and then handles it specially with a runtime check.

The first condition handles the case where we are in the `=` section, which means that we are in the overlapping region where the values in one can be represented in the other without change. The `shift_by_window` function in the code moves all values down by the size of each of these segments (we have to subtract the max value then subtract 1 to avoid arithmetic overflow issues). If we are outside of that region (we are in the `+` region), we need to jump down by one window size. This puts us in the overlapping range, which means we can safely convert from unsigned to signed because there is no change in value. However, we are not done yet because we have mapped two unsigned values to each signed value. Therefore, we need to shift down to the next window (the `-` region) so that we have a unique mapping again.

Now, does this give us a result congruent mod `UINT_MAX + 1`, as requested in the question? `UINT_MAX + 1` is equivalent to `2^n`, where `n` is the number of bits in the value representation. The value we use for our window size is equal to `2^(n - 1)` (the final index in a sequence of values is one less than the size). We subtract that value twice, which means we subtract `2 * 2^(n - 1)` which is equal to `2^n`. Adding and subtracting `x` is a no-op in arithmetic mod `x`, so we have not affected the original value mod `2^n`.

### Properly handling integer promotions

Because this is a generic function and not just `int` and `unsigned`, we also have to concern ourselves with integral promotion rules. There are two possibly interesting cases: one in which `short` is smaller than `int` and one in which `short` is the same size as `int`.

#### Example: `short` smaller than `int`

If `short` is smaller than `int` (common on modern platforms) then we also know that `unsigned short` can fit in an `int`, which means that any operations on it will actually happen in `int`, so we explicitly cast to the promoted type to avoid this. Our final statement is pretty abstract and becomes easier to understand if we substitute in real values. For our first interesting case, with no loss of generality let us consider a 16-bit `short` and a 17-bit `int` (which is still allowed under the new rules, and would just mean that at least one of those two integer types have some padding bits):

```
constexpr auto shift_by_window = [](auto x) {
    return x - static_cast<decltype(x)>(32767) - 1;
};
return static_cast<int16_t>(
    shift_by_window(
        static_cast<int17_t>(
            shift_by_window(
                static_cast<uint17_t>(value)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Solving for the greatest possible 16-bit unsigned value

```
constexpr auto shift_by_window = [](auto x) {
    return x - static_cast<decltype(x)>(32767) - 1;
};
return int16_t(
    shift_by_window(
        int17_t(
            shift_by_window(
                uint17_t(65535)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Simplifies to

```
return int16_t(
    int17_t(
        uint17_t(65535) - uint17_t(32767) - 1
    ) -
    int17_t(32767) -
    1
);
```

Simplifies to

```
return int16_t(
    int17_t(uint17_t(32767)) -
    int17_t(32767) -
    1
);
```

Simplifies to

```
return int16_t(
    int17_t(32767) -
    int17_t(32767) -
    1
);
```

Simplifies to

```
return int16_t(-1);
```

We put in the largest possible unsigned and get back `-1`, success!

#### Example: `short` same size as `int`

If `short` is the same size as `int` (uncommon on modern platforms), the integral promotion rule are slightly different. In this case, `short` promotes to `int` and `unsigned short` promotes to `unsigned`. Fortunately, we explicitly cast each result to the type we want to do the calculation in, so we end up with no problematic promotions. With no loss of generality let us consider a 16-bit `short` and a 16-bit `int`:

```
constexpr auto shift_by_window = [](auto x) {
    return x - static_cast<decltype(x)>(32767) - 1;
};
return static_cast<int16_t>(
    shift_by_window(
        static_cast<int16_t>(
            shift_by_window(
                static_cast<uint16_t>(value)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Solving for the greatest possible 16-bit unsigned value

```
auto x = int16_t(
    uint16_t(65535) - uint16_t(32767) - 1
);
return int16_t(
    x - int16_t(32767) - 1
);
```

Simplifies to

```
return int16_t(
    int16_t(32767) - int16_t(32767) - 1
);
```

Simplifies to

```
return int16_t(-1);
```

We put in the largest possible unsigned and get back `-1`, success!

### What if I just care about `int` and `unsigned` and don't care about warnings, like the original question?

```
constexpr int cast_to_signed_integer(unsigned const value) {
    using result_limits = std::numeric_limits<int>;
    if constexpr (result_limits::min() + 1 != -result_limits::max()) {
        if (value == static_cast<unsigned>(result_limits::max()) + 1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot convert the maximum possible unsigned to a signed value on this system");
        }
    }
    if (value <= result_limits::max()) {
        return static_cast<int>(value);
    } else {
        constexpr int window = result_limits::min();
        return static_cast<int>(value + window) + window;
    }
}
```

### See it live

https://godbolt.org/z/74hY81

Here we see that clang, gcc, and icc generate no code for `cast` and `cast_to_signed_integer_basic` at `-O2` and `-O3`, and MSVC generates no code at `/O2`, so the solution is optimal.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly tell the compiler what you want to do:

```
int unsigned_to_signed(unsigned n) {
  if (n > INT_MAX) {
    if (n <= UINT_MAX + INT_MIN) {
      throw "no result";
    }
    return static_cast<int>(n + INT_MIN) - (UINT_MAX + INT_MIN + 1);
  } else {
    return static_cast<int>(n);
  }
}
```

Compiles with `gcc 4.7.2` for `x86_64-linux` (`g++ -O -S test.cpp`) to

```
_Z18unsigned_to_signedj:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    ret
```

Comment: `UINT_MAX` is an expression of type `unsigned int`, and that makes your whole `static_cast<int>(n + INT_MIN) - (UINT_MAX + INT_MIN + 1)` of that type. It should be possible to fix that, though, and I expect it to then still be compiled the same.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is our input...

If `x > INT_MAX`, we want to find a constant `k` such that `0` < `x - k*INT_MAX` < `INT_MAX`.

This is easy -- `unsigned int k = x / INT_MAX;`.  Then, let `unsigned int x2 = x - k*INT_MAX;`

We can now cast `x2` to `int` safely.  Let `int x3 = static_cast<int>(x2);`

We now want to subtract something like `UINT_MAX - k * INT_MAX + 1` from `x3`, if `k > 0`.

Now, on a 2s complement system, so long as `x > INT_MAX`, this works out to:

```
unsigned int k = x / INT_MAX;
x -= k*INT_MAX;
int r = int(x);
r += k*INT_MAX;
r -= UINT_MAX+1;
```

Note that `UINT_MAX+1` is zero in C++ guaranteed, the conversion to int was a noop, and we subtracted `k*INT_MAX` then added it back on "the same value".  So an acceptable optimizer should be able to erase all that tomfoolery!

That leaves the problem of `x > INT_MAX` or not.  Well, we create 2 branches, one with `x > INT_MAX`, and one without.  The one without does a strait cast, which the compiler optimizes to a noop.  The one with ... does a noop after the optimizer is done.  The smart optimizer realizes both branches to the same thing, and drops the branch.

Issues: if `UINT_MAX` is really large relative to `INT_MAX`, the above might not work.  I am assuming that `k*INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX+1` implicitly.

We could probably attack this with some enums like:

```
enum { divisor = UINT_MAX/INT_MAX, remainder = UINT_MAX-divisor*INT_MAX };
```

which work out to 2 and 1 on a 2s complement system I believe (are we guaranteed for that math to work?  That's tricky...), and do logic based on these that easily optimize away on non-2s complement systems...

This also opens up the exception case.  It is only possible if UINT_MAX is much larger than (INT_MIN-INT_MAX), so you can put your exception code in an if block asking exactly that question somehow, and it won't slow you down on a traditional system.

I'm not exactly sure how to construct those compile-time constants to deal correctly with that.

Comment: `UINT_MAX` cannot be small relative to `INT_MAX`, because the spec guarantees that every positive signed int is representable as an unsigned int.  But `UINT_MAX+1` is zero on every system; unsigned arithmetic is always modulo `UINT_MAX+1`.  Still there might be a kernel of a workable approach here...

Comment: @Nemo Just following this thread, so pardon my potentially obvious question: Is your statement "`UINT_MAX+1` is zero on every system` established in the '03-spec? If so, is there a specific subsection I should be looking under? Thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Section 3.9.1 paragraph 4: "Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer", with a footnote saying "This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type."  Basically unsigned is specified to work the way you want/expect.

Answer (score 1):

`std::numeric_limits<int>::is_modulo` is a compile time constant. so you can use it for template specialization. problem solved, at least if compiler plays along with inlining.

```
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

#ifdef TESTING_SF
    bool const testing_sf = true;
#else
    bool const testing_sf = false;
#endif

// C++ "extensions"
namespace cppx {
    using std::runtime_error;
    using std::string;

    inline bool hopefully( bool const c ) { return c; }
    inline bool throw_x( string const& s ) { throw runtime_error( s ); }

}  // namespace cppx

// C++ "portability perversions"
namespace cppp {
    using cppx::hopefully;
    using cppx::throw_x;
    using std::numeric_limits;

    namespace detail {
        template< bool isTwosComplement >
        int signed_from( unsigned const n )
        {
            if( n <= unsigned( numeric_limits<int>::max() ) )
            {
                return static_cast<int>( n );
            }

            unsigned const u_max = unsigned( -1 );
            unsigned const u_half = u_max/2 + 1;

            if( n == u_half )
            {
                throw_x( "signed_from: unsupported value (negative max)" );
            }

            int const i_quarter = static_cast<int>( u_half/2 );
            int const int_n1 = static_cast<int>( n - u_half );
            int const int_n2 = int_n1 - i_quarter;
            int const int_n3 = int_n2 - i_quarter;

            hopefully( n == static_cast<unsigned>( int_n3 ) )
                || throw_x( "signed_from: range error" );

            return int_n3;
        }

        template<>
        inline int signed_from<true>( unsigned const n )
        {
            return static_cast<int>( n );
        }
    }    // namespace detail

    inline int signed_from( unsigned const n )
    {
        bool const is_modulo = numeric_limits< int >::is_modulo;
        return detail::signed_from< is_modulo && !testing_sf >( n );
    }
}    // namespace cppp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int const x = cppp::signed_from( -42u );
    wcout << x << endl;
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Fixed up code to avoid possible trap on non-modular-int machines (only one is known to exist, namely the archaically configured versions of the Unisys Clearpath). For simplicity this is done by not supporting the value -2<sup>*n*-1</sup> where *n* is the number of `int` value bits, on such machine (i.e., on the Clearpath). in practice this value will not be supported by the machine either (i.e., with sign-and-magnitude or 1’s complement representation).

Answer (score 1):

I think the int type is at least two bytes, so the INT_MIN and INT_MAX may change in different platforms.

[Fundamental types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

[≤climits≥ header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/)

Comment: I am cursed to use a compiler for the 6809 which is configured with "-mint8" by default, where int is 8 bits :-(  (this is the development environment for the Vectrex) long is 2 bytes, long long is 4 bytes and I have no idea what short is...

Comment: @GrahamToal - What you've described is not a conforming standard C implementation. C requires an `int` and a `short` to contain at least 16 bits of information.

Comment: Hence the word 'cursed'. I'm well aware it is an idiotic thing to do and I've argued with the people responsible for this decision but it isn't going to change and the support library is written assuming this, so turning it off isn't practical either. Here's how it is described in the gcc6809 documentation: (shortened to fit) “int” is 16 bits wide. “short” or “char” both are 8-bits.  “long” is 32 bits, or 4 bytes wide.  Optionally, you can make integers 8 bits wide, by using the -mint8 command-line option. This also shortens the size of “long” to 16 bits. It does not affect “short” or “char”.

Answer (score 1):

My money is on using memcpy. Any decent compiler knows to optimise it away:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <limits.h>

static inline int unsigned_to_signed(unsigned n)
{
    int result;
    memcpy( &result, &n, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int x = UINT_MAX - 1;
    int xx = unsigned_to_signed(x);
    return xx;
}
```

For me (Xcode 8.3.2, Apple LLVM 8.1, -O3), that produces:

```
_main:                                  ## @main
Lfunc_begin0:
    .loc    1 21 0                  ## /Users/Someone/main.c:21:0
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq    %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argc <- %EDI
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argv <- %RSI
Ltmp3:
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:x <- 2147483646
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:xx <- 2147483646
    .loc    1 24 5 prologue_end     ## /Users/Someone/main.c:24:5
    movl    $-2, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
Ltmp4:
Lfunc_end0:
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the binary representation of an unsigned is _not_ guaranteed by the standard to match the signed representation.