# type casting boost multiprecision integer returns wrong answer

Tags: c++, boost

The issue I am facing is with boost multiprecision **cpp_int** type casting to a small integer type **int16_t**.
Typecasting unsigned integer value of **43690** to **int16_t** is supposed to return **-21846**, however what I am getting is **32767**. Am I missing anything here?

Here is the sample snippet of code to reproduce the behavior

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
typedef boost::multiprecision::uint128_t uint_xt;
using namespace std;
int main() {
    uint_xt a = 43690;
    uint64_t c = 43690;
    int16_t b = static_cast<int16_t>(a);
    int16_t d =  static_cast<int16_t>(c);
    cout << b << ", " << d << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Output: 32767, -21846

Edit: The issue lies with implementation defined behavior of cast in case of overflow.[Efficient unsigned-to-signed cast avoiding implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150449/efficient-unsigned-to-signed-cast-avoiding-implementation-defined-behavior) seems to have an answer for this.

Comment: Did you check what the conversion does in case of overflow?

Comment: I get this is undefined behavior now, not sure why the question itself has been downvoted though. The reason for doing this casting inspite of overflow is more from assembly perspective. A signed load instruction, what value it would read if the memory content has some value. To achieve this I had used cast. I get this behavior now. Thanks

Comment: @idclev463035818 the reason being the answer I got with python numpy, and if the same value is uint64_t. Also, if you just follow the bit pattern and treat that as signed value, you would get -21856 for 43690.

Comment: [signed overflow is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c). That the bits can be interpreted as a negative `int` doesn't really matter, because the compiler could generate code that prints `42` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this line first:

```
int16_t d =  static_cast<int16_t>(c);
```

This follows the [conv.integral#3](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3) clause of the C++ Standard about integer conversions between builtin types:

> Otherwise *[i.e. the destination type is not `bool`]*, the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is the width of the destination type.

Now to this line:

```
int16_t b = static_cast<int16_t>(a);
```

This follows the Boost implementation of the handling of conversion overflow in `boost::multiprecision::backends::eval_convert_to`, defined in `boost/multiprecision/cpp_int/misc.hpp`:

```
/*<return type skipped>*/
   eval_convert_to(R* result, const cpp_int_backend</*skipped*/>& val)
{
   typedef typename /*<skipped>*/ common_type;
   if(std::numeric_limits<R>::is_specialized && (static_cast<common_type>(*val.limbs()) > static_cast<common_type>((std::numeric_limits<R>::max)())))
   {
      conversion_overflow(/*<arguments skipped>*/);
      *result = (std::numeric_limits<R>::max)();
   }
   else
      *result = static_cast<R>(*val.limbs());
}
```

As you can see, the result returned is the maximum value for the target type, which is not what the compiler is doing for the built-in types. But it's not wrong, it's just a bit unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

you basically try to convert int **128 & 64** to **16**
for example :

```
sizeof int16_t = 2B
sizeof int64_t = 8B
```

& you want to **convert something with 8B in size to 2B**
**basically what you get** it's a **wrong values** even you use **C style**.

to avoid this problems you should care about sizes when you deal with datatypes
for example :

```
uint64_t  c = 43690;
int64_t d = (int64_t)(c);
```