# Behavior of reintepret_cast of CUDA pointers?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, reinterpret-cast

Considering the following **host** function:

```
uint64_t * SomeDevPtr =...
/* Where SomeDevPtr is a pointer pointed to some device memory address allocated by cudaMalloc(); */

uint32_t * SomeDevIntPtr = reintepret_cast<uint32_t *>(SomeDevPtr);
```

Because of the function, `cudaMalloc` will automatcially fullfill some aligment requirements (I think it is aligned to some 128 byte memory boundary), therefore I think both `SomeDevIntPtr` and `SomeDevPtr` should be start at exact the same physical memory address at GPU's global memory, am I correct on this?

I just want to make sure about that since some of the functions I wrote depend on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `reinterpret_cast` of a *pointer* to a *pointer* [does not](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/cast.html) (ie. should not) change the underlying numerical value (bit pattern representation) of a pointer.

Therefore whatever alignment conditions exist will not be affected by that kind of cast.

It's possible of course, to cast a properly aligned pointer to a type that no longer has proper alignment.  For example, a properly aligned `float` pointer that is not at an evenly-divisible-by-4 `float` offset (index) cannot be properly cast to a `float4` pointer *for CUDA device usage*.  Some CUDA pointers need to be naturally aligned.

You may also be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218465/when-does-casting-change-a-values-bits-in-c).